# Prove that $\|w-v\|_2 \leq \sqrt{n}/2$

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, combinatorics, normed-spaces

Let $v_i$ be a vector in $R^n$ with $\|v_i\|_2 \leq 1$. Let $a_i$ be a constant in $[0, 1]$ for $i = 1, 2, ..., n$. Prove that there exist $b_1, b_2, ..., b_n \in \{0, 1\}$ such that $\|w-v\|_2 \leq \sqrt{n}/2$, where $w = \sum_{i=1}^{n}a_iv_i$, $v = \sum_{i=1}^{n}b_iv_i$.

My try:

Pick $b_i$ independently with $P(b_i=1)=a_i$ and $P(b_i=0)=1-a_i$.

$\|w-v\|_2 = \|\sum_{i=1}^n(a_i-b_i)v_i\|_2 \leq \sum_{i=1}^n|a_i-b_i|\|v_i\|_2 \leq \sum_{i=1}^n|a_i-b_i|$.

$E(|a_i-b_i|)=a_i(1-a_i)+(1-a_i)a_i \leq 1/2$.

Then, $\sum_{i=1}^n|a_i-b_i|\leq n/2$.

I can just prove the bound is $n/2$.

Comment: does this help? https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h69947p408639

Comment: Yes. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Basically, look at the expectation of the **squared** $\ell_2$ norm instead of the $\ell_2$ norm, Things are much nicer.

Comment: @Steven01123581321 Sorry, I am confused by one step in your link. Why $ \sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}E(x_i-e_i)(x_j-e_j)\langle u_i, u_j\rangle = \sum_{i=1}^nE((x_i-e_i)^2)\langle u_i, u_i \rangle$?